# delete array elements by certain criteria

Tags: ruby, arrays

What's the best and way to do this:
I have two arrays:

```
a=[['a','one'],['b','two'],['c','three'],['d','four']]
```

and `b=['two','three']`

I want to delete nested arrays inside `a` that include elements in `b`,to get this:

```
[['a','one']['d','four']
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
a = [['a','one'],['b','two'],['c','three'],['d','four']]
b = ['two','three']

a.delete_if { |x| b.include?(x.last) }

p a
# => [["a", "one"], ["d", "four"]]
```

Answer (score 5):

rassoc to the rescue!

```
 b.each {|el| a.delete(a.rassoc(el)) }
```

Comment: Wow - Ruby has a method for everything - funky!

Answer (score 2):

```
a=[['a','one'],['b','two'],['c','three'],['d','four']]
b=['two','three']    
result=a.reject { |e| b.include?(e.first) or b.include?(e.last) }
# result => [["a", "one"], ["d", "four"]]
```